# Drag&Drop a picture and then submit the form to php code?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I want to upload a picture to a form and then do further things with php after submitting the form.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadform">
<input type="file" name="picture" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="Submit!" /><br />
</form>
```

This should be a drag&drop-field which automatically submits the forms after a file is inserted.
How do i do that? Looks like most libraries do a collback function on a php-file which handels the pictures than, but I want to work with it after the form is submitted to the same file again.

Means, the

```
<input type="file" name="picture" value="" /><br />
```

should be able to drag&drop and submit the form without any further clicks.

Is there a way?

//

I am so far now, that Iam using DropzoneJS with the index.php as form-action.
The image file is now processed correctly. The only thing I want to do now is to redirect to another after the upload of this *one* has finished. There is everytime only one file per form submit.

How do I configure DropZoneJS to redirect after file is uploaded?

//

Nah, my code did work all the time, but I included the dropzone.min.js, not the dropzone.js -____-

Comment: What kind of file is your "same file"?

Comment: It's the index.php in which the script does run.